# Fine Uploader S3- resize image before uploading

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using fineUploaderS3() to upload several images to S3. What I would like to do is select a file for upload, resize to a smaller size and upload the smaller file to S3 instead of the original.

I am trying to do this when 'submit' gets triggered:

on('submit', function(event, id, fileName) {

```
var uploadedFile = jQuery(this).fineUploader('getFile', id);                        
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var smallerImageUrl = resizeImage(e.target.result);
var smallerImageBlob = dataURItoBlob(smallerImageUrl);
jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('addBlobs', smallerImageBlob);
jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('cancel', id);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile);
```

})

**However, this does not seem to work. Either the call to S3 gets aborted, or the file does not get written to S3.**

Can you please recommend the best way to do this? Is there any kind of native support in Fine Uploader for this?

*Definitions of functions to resize and to convert dataURL to Blob:*

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

```
var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

try {
    return new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
} catch (e) {
    var BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(ab);
return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
}
```

}

function resizeImage(source)
{

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = source;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);       
var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;                 
if (width > height) {
    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
    width = MAX_WIDTH;
}
} else {
if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
   width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
   height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    }
}
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
return dataUrl;
```

}

---

MORE INFO:

This is a bigger chunk of my code:

jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({

```
   uploaderType: 'basic',
   maxConnections: 3,
   button: jQuery('#select'),
   request: {
      endpoint: our endpoint url,
      accessKey: our access key
    },

   objectProperties: {
           acl: 'public-read',
           key: function(id) {
                var regEx = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
                var name = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('getName', id);
                var udid = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('getUuid', id);
                var extension = regEx.exec(name)[1];
                return location of file on S3;
            }
   },
   signature: {
           endpoint: signature endpoint
   },
   uploadSuccess: {
           endpoint: upload success url,
           params: {
                   type: 'me',
                   width: 170,
                   height: 170
            }
   },
   iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: blank page url
   },
   retry: {
            showButton: true
   },
   chunking: {
            enabled: true
   },
   resume: {
             enabled: true
   },
   deleteFile: {
             enabled: true,
             method: "POST",
             endpoint: our delete endpoint
   },
   validation: {
             sizeLimit: 15000000
   }
```

}).on('submit', function(event, id, fileName) {

```
             var uploadedFile = jQuery(this).fineUploader('getFile', id);
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
             var smallerImageUrl = resizeImage(e.target.result);
             var smallerImageBlob = dataURItoBlob(smallerImageUrl);
             jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('addBlobs', smallerImageBlob);
             jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('cancel', id);
 };
 reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile);
```

})

There's code for other events like "submitted", "cancel", "progress", "complete" which I can share if required.

With this, when I try to upload one file, I see this in Firebug:

**Request to our signature endpoint URL:**

{"expiration":"2013-11-27T14:08:39.751Z","conditions":[{"acl":"public-read"},{"bucket":"xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com"},{"Content-Type":"image/jpeg"},{"success_action_status":"200"},{"key":"xxxxxx/xxxxxx/20e53c0c-d29e-410c-b2d0-2856861d187e.jpg"},{"x-amz-meta-qqfilename":"cbr1.jpg"},["content-length-range","0","15000000"]]}

**Response to this:**

{"policy":"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxMy0xMS0yN1QxNDowODozOS43NTFaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6InN5ZG5leS5pbmtpdmUuY29tIn0seyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiJpbWFnZVwvanBlZyJ9LHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAwIn0seyJrZXkiOiJzeWRuZXlcL29yaWdpbmFsXC8yMGU1M2MwYy1kMjllLTQxMGMtYjJkMC0yODU2ODYxZDE4N2UuanBnIn0seyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXFxZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJjYnIxLmpwZyJ9LFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCIwIiwiMTUwMDAwMDAiXV19","signature":"P590iCwLUlTnXo+Ek0e4H/7Z3k0="}

**Request to our S3 endpoint (there was no response as this was aborted):**

-----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key" xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/20e53c0c-d29e-410c-b2d0-2856861d187e.jpg -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type" image/jpeg -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status" 200 -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl" public-read -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-qqfilename" cbr1.jpg -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy" eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxMy0xMS0yN1QxNDowODozOS43NTFaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6InN5ZG5leS5pbmtpdmUuY29tIn0seyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiJpbWFnZVwvanBlZyJ9LHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAwIn0seyJrZXkiOiJzeWRuZXlcL29yaWdpbmFsXC8yMGU1M2MwYy1kMjllLTQxMGMtYjJkMC0yODU2ODYxZDE4N2UuanBnIn0seyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXFxZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJjYnIxLmpwZyJ9LFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCIwIiwiMTUwMDAwMDAiXV19 -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature" P590iCwLUlTnXo+Ek0e4H/7Z3k0= -----------------------------2084011506152072170779848208 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="cbr1.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg

---

The "complete" event did not get triggered.
So in this case, nothing got uploaded. The larger original image did not get uploaded because of this line in the "submit" even handler- *jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3('cancel', id)*, but the issue is that the smaller resized image did not get uploaded either.

Please let me know if you need more information.

---

**Firebug and Chrome Javascript console logs with debug: true in Fine Uploader:**

**FIREBUG:**

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received 1 files or inputs.
all.fi....min.js (line 16)

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
all.fi....min.js (line 16)

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 0
all.fi....min.js (line 16)

POST our signature URL
200 OK 52ms 
all.fi....min.js (line 17)

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 0
all.fi....min.js (line 16)

POST our S3 bucket
Aborted
all.fi....min.js (line 19)

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 0
all.fi....min.js (line 16)

**CHROME:**

It seems to go in an *infinite loop* in Chrome. I tried to upload just one photo and I see this:

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received 1 files or inputs. all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 0 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 0 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 0 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 1 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 1 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 0 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 2 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 2 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 1 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 1 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 3 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 3 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 2 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 2 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 4 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 4 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 3 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 3 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 5 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 5 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 4 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 4 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 6 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 6 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 5 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 5 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 7 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 7 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 6 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 6 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 8 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 8 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 7 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 7 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16
6

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'loaded' of undefined all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:19

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 9 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 9 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 8 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 8 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16
6

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'loaded' of undefined all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:19

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 10 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 10 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 9 all.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:16
4

Note- before I started trying to resize and send the resized file instead of the original, Fine Uploader was working fine for me. I have used it to upload several files to S3 in the past.

Comment: You will have to provide more specific information regarding your issue.  What are you seeing in the javascript console?  What specifically is happening and not happening?  If you are passing a valid blob to addBlobs, the file will be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. Have provided more information. Please scroll down to see.

Comment: What are you seeing in the javascript console?  Set the `debug` option to true and report all console log messages as well.

Comment: Have updated the question with Firebug and Chrome Javascript logs. Thanks.

Comment: Slightly unrelated question- does Fine Uploader have built-in support for resizing images that I want to upload? I want to resize the image, upload the resized image AND retain a handle to the original file so that I can upload it later (maybe asynchronously), without making the user wait for several large files to upload.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at your issue in the next couple days.  As to your question regarding uploads of resized images, please see (and possibly comment on) case 1061 at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1061.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Will have a look.

Comment: This feature is now complete in the develop branch, and is a planned part of the upcoming 4.4 release. Read more at docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/features/scaling.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code will always result in an infinite loop.  In your onSubmit, you are submitting a scaled version of the file, and cancelling the original, but then that scaled file is hitting onSubmit and you are starting the cycle over again, with no obvious end.

You have two options:

1. Wait until Fine Uploader adds native support for automatic scaled image uploads (optionally alongside the original).  This is being discussed in feature request in [issue #1061 in the project's Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1061).
2. Setup two Fine Uploader instances on your page.  One instance will receive the original file, generate the scaled version, and then submit it programmatically via the `addBlobs` method on the 2nd instance.